# Cannot reach node on virtual machine using Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, grid, virtual-machine, virtualbox, nodes

I launched a **hub** on the physical machine (Windows 10, RAM 16Gb, x64): 

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub port 4444`

Also I registered a **node** on the virtual machine (I use VirtualBox: Linux, Ubuntu 16.04.2; i386. Base memory: 2048 Mb):

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role webdriver port 9999 -hub http://172.xx.xxx.248:4444/grid/register`

Node is visible from grid console, but **connection is failed**
[image: Grid console]
Cannot run tests.

Configurations in IDE: 
`WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.0.2.15:9999/wd/hub"), capabilities);`

Error while running the tests: 
`org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 10.0.2.15:9999 [/10.0.2.15] failed: Connection timed out: connect`

Physical machine address: 172.xx.xxx.248 
Virtual machine address: 10.0.2.15

Comment: are you able to log into the virtual machine and launch a browser manually?

Comment: yes, I can launch firefox manually in /usr/bin directory on virtual Linux machine

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution. VM (VirtualBox in my case) should be configured the following way:

Go to Settings -> Network

 1. *Attached to* should be **'Bridged Adapter'**

 2. Expand 'Advanced' -> *Promiscuous mode* should be **'Allow All'**[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are starting your RemoteWebDriver with wrong URL, you should give it hub IP to register on, not node IP.

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://172.xx.xxx.248:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't help. I receive the same exception 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.... Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 172.xx.xxx.248:9998 [/172.xx.xxx.248] failed: Connection refused: connect

Comment: And which version of firefox are you using?

Comment: firefox version on VM - 47.0

Comment: maybe, the reason was - the VM network I used, it was NAT.
when I changed to Bridged Adapter - the exception was also changed to:
`org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms`